# Firefox debugging repl in emacs?

Tags: slime

It looks like firefox has a remote debugging protocol,

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Remote_Debugging_Protocol

Does anyone know of any tools that would allow emacs to make a connection and to allow debugging from within emacs? Maybe I should file a feature request to port their protocol to a swank/slime protocol?

Comment: That sounds like a bad idea considering all but the official contrib implementations for SLIME did bitrot away.

Comment: I'm not sure if those use this protocol or something else, but there's MozRepl and swnak-js, both of which can be used from Emacs.

Comment: what does bitrot away mean to you? because I use slime/swank every day and it's immensely useful. I also find it a pretty stable software

Comment: @wvxvw I tried swank-js, it is severely unmaintained but I did get it to work after fixing some deprecations. But, this allows me to run code within a tab, what I need is access to the browser console context or the remote debugging context for an extension.

Comment: Mmm... I also know that keysnail can both access the browser console and it can communicate to Emacs, but I'm not sure how difficult it would be to set it up to do what you want, although, I know it has a bunch of plugins--maybe there's something already there?

Answer (score 1):

This is an extremely late answer, but two additional possibilities exist:
[emacs-firefox-remote](https://github.com/ruediger/emacs-firefox-remote) and [jss](https://github.com/segv/jss). Neither has unfortunately been maintained in a rather long time.

The former does seem to at least have the ability to connect to firefox, retrieve some sort of information, and disconnect, though not very much else.

The latter is designed to be more extensive, providing support for debugging chromium as well. (However, I have not tested it, as in its case the code seems to be far too extensive to casually inspect, to ensure that it doesn't do something crazy.)

I hope that this is of some value to somebody.